# Bulk changing Issuer of Patient ID on PACS (DCM4CHEE)

Tags: hl7, dcm4che

i need to update around 1,5k patient records with `Issuer of Patient` ID on DCM4CHEE PACS server.

I figured i will manage to do it efficiently through HL7 messages (either `A31` or `A08`) though i cannot find appropriate syntax to do it nowhere.

If anyone knows how to do it (in this or any other way) i would be most grateful
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to modify bunch of records that already exist in the PACS database then doing an SQL update directly upon the dcm4chee data structures (some description is available at http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/ee2/Database+Table+Descriptions) might be easier.. just a hint

Comment: Well, that was also my first idea, but manually changing pat_id_issuer in patient table doesn't really change it: for instance in web3 interface such modified record is found when filtering by issuer, though display doesn't indicate issuer at all, like there wasn't one. Also all ambigiuity problems with patient matching stays. It may be I should change some other fields in db, but again i have no clue which one... :/

Comment: I don't know, you might find out more by reversing the source codes, but the answer may be already available in dcm4chee support forums at http://forums.dcm4che.org/jiveforums/index.jspa?categoryID=1 and you may also get your answer by asking at dcm4chee development Google group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dcm4che - try digging there first. Stack Overflow does not have very strong healthcare IT community, although you may vote for the [area51 healthcare IT proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65896/healthcare-it?referrer=zzSEh1b0idFc27gzFOBXTQ2) to change it(?)

Comment: I looked it up on Google group - no luck there, i will check on forum though.  Digging through source is exactly the part i would like to avoid. Currently im musing on using some kind of browser automation for semi-automatic solution...

Comment: I would strongly go against doing a simple SQL update when changing this many patient records - it breaks chain of custody and will wreck havoc on any auditing records.  I don't know anything about DCM4CHE, but usually the Issuer of ID is based around the original patient registration and PID.3 + Sending Application in the message header in HL7 messages.  Do you know what field exactly your PACS system is using to populate pat_id_issuer?

Comment: well it can be send in hl7 message, set up manually via built-in web interface, it may come in image as tag and it also may be automatically assigned for specified modality - but it doesn't matters actually. among all solutions currently im going with sending ADT^31 (web interface sucks so browser automation wasn't such bright idea i thought it was, nice experiment though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all i went with script sending HL7 message `ADT^A08` for each record i'd like to modify.

Since i wanted to update only this patients that didn't have `Issuer of Patient ID` already, and dcm4chee-web3 interface does not support filtering in that manner (cannot search for 'does not have an issuer') i had no choice but to go into database.

I queried PACS database for patients with empty `pat_issuer` field and exported returned results to file

Then i ran my script which walked through the file line by line, put data in above-mentioned HL7 message and send it to server (i used python-hl7 library which also provides command line utility for sending HL7).

It worked well and didn't take a lot of time either to write it, and to use it so i will deem it answer to my question.

Comment: Could you please help me with documentation to create the HL7 you have made. How to send it to the PACS. And how to received. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @andres83 i'd be happy to help you if i can, but you need to elaborate a little more, about what do you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I do not understand how did you create the HL7 message. Which tools did you use? How to make the template and how to send the message to the PACS. I am really sorry, to ask this silly questions but I haven´t find much information on the web. By the way do you know how to change the ID (not the Issuer but the primary key) Thanks again.

Comment: @andres83 well, hl7 has closed docs so it is little harder than usual to figure things out. I did manage to find good reference though: http://www.mexi.be/documents/hl7/httoc.htm For changing Issuer i did use an ADT^A08 message and to change ID's (both internal and external) there is special kind of messages - ADT^A46 to 48. Thats it for now - check it and then im happy to answer any futher questions (provided i'll be able to)